# Pear Mails sends mails also with invalid smtp user

Tags: php, pear

I want to use the pear mail extension to send SMTP authenticated emails.
There are a lot of examples in the web... this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$body = "Testtext";
$subject = "SMTP Testmail";
$mail_to = "valid.adress@test.com";
$mail_from = "valid.sender.adress@othertest.com";

//SMTP Verbindungsdaten
$host = "valid.smtp.com";
$username = "invalidusername@othertest.com";
$password = "validpasswordforotheruser";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
 array (
 'host' => $host,
 //'auth' => true,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password
));

$headers = array (
 'From' => $mail_from,
 'To' => $mail_to,
 'Subject' => $subject
);
$mail = $smtp->send($mail_to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo "Error during sending E-Mail : ". $mail->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The script worked well so I wanted to test the error case of this sample and changed the smtp user to something invalid and it sill worked... I have got my mail.

How can this be?

Greetings

edit:
I have done an other test now and changed the smtp server to be something invalid... documentation say that there must be an "PEAR_MAIL_SMTP_ERROR_CONNECT" error... I'm getting the following output:
"fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to **xx.xx.xx.xxx:25** (Connection refused) in /usr/local/lib/php/Net/Socket.php on line 108"

"Catchable fatal error: Object of class PEAR_Error could not be converted to string in /usr/local/lib/php/Net/SMTP.php on line 222"

Where does this IP coming from when the smtp name is invalid???
Can it be the server is overrules by any config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the SMTP server does not validate the login data. It might not require authentication at all or support SMPT-after-POP (a horribly outdated thing by the way), i.e. if your IP authenticated on the corresponsing POP3 server recently the SMTP server will not require you to authenticate.

Try changing the *server* to something that is likely to require authentication all the time, e.g. the gmail SMTP.

Comment: The server is from a web hoster I dont know... possible that they have anonymus access allowed (but I would be suprised).
Anyway... there is no magical fallback in pear mail which uses php mail or something like that as fallback? And do you have an idea how I can test the error case? (I want to get an error from "send")

Comment: The best way for testing that would be to start a fake smtp server that does nothing but respond with an error.